# Changing a list into a string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, spyder

I have a list like this:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to change it into a string, get rid of the quotes, and get rid of the commas so that it looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

I tried the following:

```
new_list = []
new_list.append(li)
new_string = " ".join(new_list)
print new_string
```

however I get the below error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Why does this happen and how can I fix this so that I get the output I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from attempting to join integers into a string, you could do this to turn every value into a string, then join them.

```
new_list = [str(x) for x in li]
new_string = " ".join(new_list)
```

As a one-liner:

```
new_string = " ".join([str(x) for x in li])
```

Answer (score 3):

The items in the list need to be of the `str` type in order to join them with the given delimeter. Try this:

```
' '.join(map(str, your_list)) # join the resulting iterable of strings, after casting ints
```

Comment: `your_list` in this case would be `li`

Comment: I have no idea why you are appending your list to `new_list` in order to join.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because join is expecting an iterable sequence of strings, and yours contains int.

You need to convert this list to string either by using list comprehension:

```
>>> li 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> new_li = [str(val) for val in li]
>>> new_li
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

or a regular for loop:

```
   >>> for x in range(len(li)):
    ...     li[x] = str(li[x])
    ...     
    >>> li
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

then your expression will work.

```
>>> result = ' '.join(li)
>>> result
'1 2 3 4 5'
```